# BroadcastReceiver not receiving category intents

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, categories

I have the following code, which works well if my receiver uses an intentFilter for a specific action, but does not work if, instead, my receiver awaits on a whole category. I've tried some examples on the web, not sure why it does not work, I also tried removing the action reference and only leave the category... can some one pls have a look?

My activity:

```
public class Receiver1Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addCategory(MyService.MY_CATEGORY);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("activity", "onStart");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("activity", "onPause");
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
}

private MyReceiver myReceiver;
}
```

My service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public static final String MY_CATEGORY = "com.receiver1.mycategory";
public static final String MY_ACTION = "com.receiver1.myaction";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MY_ACTION);
    intent2.addCategory(MY_CATEGORY);
    sendBroadcast(intent2);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

My receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Log.i("MyReceiver", "onreceive");        
}
}
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.receiver1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Receiver1Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyService">
        <!-- 
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.receiver1.myaction2"/>
        </intent-filter>
         -->
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

put this also in your activity class hope it should be helpful for you

```
 @Override protected void onResume() {     
  super.onResume();     
  registerReceiver(myReceiver,filter); 
 }
```

try this..

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyService.MY_ACTION);
    filter.addCategory(MyService.MY_CATEGORY);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

instead of

```
myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addCategory(MyService.MY_CATEGORY);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

you are missing ACTION When registering Receiver

Comment: that will obviously work, but I would like my receiver to receive ANY action with that category, otherwise, if I simply add all actions explicitly, why do I need the category for?. If I change the code as you suggest, then the receiver would only receive this particular action. Nevertheless I tried your suggestion, and indeed the receiver is invoked on MY_ACTION, but if I broadcast another action, say, ACTION2, with the same category, the receiver is again not invoked.

Comment: @sagimann: "but I would like my receiver to receive ANY action with that category" -- first, that is not possible. Second, categories are not generally used with broadcasts.